# Does the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{2n^{5}+13n^{3}}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}(n^6-n^2+7)}$ converge or diverge? Justify.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Does the series $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{2n^{5}+13n^{3}}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}(n^6-n^2+7)}$$ converge or diverge? Justify.

I know that it diverges. I am trying to use the comparison test to prove it but I am having trouble finding a smaller series that diverges. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you forced to use the comparison test? Otherwise the limit comparison test will suffice.

Comment: I'm not forced to use any particular method, I just thought the comparison test would be the best choice for this.

Comment: Comparison by inequality are elegant but not so simple to see and justify in general (see DonAntonio solution for this one), with limit comparison test it becomes straightforward https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that since $n^{\frac{1}{n}}\to 1$

$$\frac{2n^{5}+13n^{3}}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}(n^6-n^2+7)}\sim \frac2n$$

then use limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1n$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{2n^5+13n^3}{\sqrt[n]n(n^6-n^2+7)}\ge\frac{2n^5}{2n^6}\;\ldots$$

Comment: Nice bounding (+1)

Comment: Why $\color{red}2\,n^6$ in the denominator?

Comment: I guess since eventually $-n^2+7<0$ Is  less than zero and $\sqrt[n] n<2$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Bernard I think that way it is easier to see that $\;\sqrt[n]n(n^6-n^2+7)\le2n^6\;$ ...WIthout 2 it is also true, of course.

Comment: @gimusi: You're right, of course, but I think it had to be detailed in some way. That explains why using equivalence usually  makes explanations shorter.

Comment: @Bernard indeed I also prefer use limit comparison, with inequality it is easy to get wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an equivalent of the term of your series
$$
\frac{2n^5+13n^3}{n^{1/n}\left(n^6-n^2+7\right)}\underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{2n^5}{n^{1/n}n^6}=\frac{2}{n^{1+1/n}}\underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{2}{n}
$$
Then it diverges.

Comment: “...by limit comparison test” should be added.